# Attaching two separate elements to one animate script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a div to change its width through hovering over it. I've got that sussed but I would also like its width to change through hovering an h5 tag which is separate. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this? Here's what I have at the moment.

```
$(function(){
$("#hoverbox").hover(
    function(){
       $(this).animate({width: '150px'});
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({width: '38px'});
    }
);
}};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0u8braj/5/ ... alternatively it's at http://www.cosmosdesign.co.nz/ . Also you may notice the box can act a little spastic and expand and retract numerous times, does this relate to my current code? Thanks.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to javascript so if this is a simple solution go easy on me.

Comment: you were close :) https://jsfiddle.net/m0u8braj/7/  i guess that this is the point were you understand that css selectors may help you not only for just web design lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0u8braj/6/). It now does what you desire with CSS only. No need for jQuery's `.animate()`

It's working like this, because CSS's `:hover` can affect sibling elements with the `+` or `~` selectors, like so:

```
#hoverbox:hover, h5:hover + #hoverbox{
  width: 150px;
}
```

Hope this helps